# How to bind a wpf table to an observablecollection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have some code to bind to an observablecollection. The problem is that I just get one row instead of getting several rows (meaning displaying all the elements in the observable collection) . How can I get all the rows for the observable collection?

```
<FlowDocumentScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" FontFamily="Arial" BorderThickness="0" >
    <FlowDocument>
        <Table Name="myTable" FontFamily="Calibri" BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuTextBrushKey}}" DataContext="{Binding}">
            <Table.Columns>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
                <TableColumn/>
            </Table.Columns>
            <TableRowGroup DataContext="{Binding}">
                <TableRow>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Activity_Name}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Data_Type}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run  Text="{Binding Insert_Succeeded}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run  Text="{Binding Insert_Failed}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Update_Succeeded}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Update_Failed}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Delete_Succeeded}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Delete_Failed}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        <Paragraph>
                            <Run Text="{Binding Skipped}"/>
                        </Paragraph>
                    </TableCell>
                <TableRow>
            </TableRowGroup>
        </Table>
    </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentScrollViewer>
```

Comment: I guess you should bind you collection with `ItemSource` property.

Comment: you can just use datacontext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The FlowDocument control does not support DataBinding as explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569761.aspx)

> While there are many great features in flow documents, if your
>   documents are generated from dynamic data, you have a bit of a
>   problem: **there is no support for data binding in flow documents**.
>   The flow document elements (Section, Table, Run, Paragraph and the
>   like) are dependency objects, but don't define any dependency
>   properties that would allow you to dynamically change or generate
>   content.

There is a work around given at the above link, which might be helpful for you.